# Swift 2: UITableView 'reloadSections' method crash in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios9, ios9.1

My app was working fine prior to the forced upgrade to Swift 2.x.  My code below is executed on an IBAction for a button that "collapses" the cell, e.g. it replaces it with another layout and then attempts to reload the cell, which for various reasons I've been forced to include each cell in its own section (so, extensibly I'm reloading the section).  I've tried outputting various variables to the terminal; the inputs are sound.  I've also tried wrapping this in .beginUpdates() and .endUpdates() and when walking through this in the debugger, it will just throw the below exception on the .endUpdates() call instead of the .reloadSections() call.  I have also tried replacing .reloadSections() with a blanket call to .reloadData() and I receive the same stack trace, making me believe it's internal to the TableView object somehow.

```
// Set Selected Patient Configuration to "Collapsed"
patientList.patients[ sender.tag ].updateConfiguration( collapsedConfiguration )
let animation = UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic

// Retrieve Current Table View and Animate Changes
let tableView = self.superview!.superview as! UITableView

// Reload Section with Animation
tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet( index: sender.tag ), withRowAnimation: animation )
```

My code will evaluate the backing data's collapsed state and draw it in either the full or collapsed view.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00e2fa84 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03235e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00cdd211 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 881
    3   Foundation                          0x01510134 -[NSKeyValueSlowMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:] + 115
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d38630 -[NSMutableArray insertObjects:count:atIndex:] + 192
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00d38322 -[NSMutableArray insertObjectsFromArray:range:atIndex:] + 322
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00d381c2 -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:] + 834
    7   UIKit                               0x024f4d4f -[UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection performConnect] + 964
    8   UIKit                               0x024f4daf -[UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection connect] + 33
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0324a00c -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00d60571 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 273
    11  UIKit                               0x021b06f6 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2102
    12  UIKit                               0x01eeed6c -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] + 457
    13  UIKit                               0x01eef173 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:] + 48
    14  Halo                                0x001b5174 _TFC4Halo18MainViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 2356
    15  Halo                                0x001be459 _TToFC4Halo18MainViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 89
    16  UIKit                               0x01f03a19 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 782
    17  UIKit                               0x01f03b47 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 90
    18  UIKit                               0x022568cc -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells] + 8353
    19  UIKit                               0x0226181a -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] + 161
    20  UIKit                               0x01ed7fd3 -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 3653
    21  UIKit                               0x01ecfc91 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 17491
    22  UIKit                               0x01eea538 -[UITableView _updateSections:updateAction:withRowAnimation:headerFooterOnly:] + 460
    23  UIKit                               0x01eea625 -[UITableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation:] + 73
    24  Halo                                0x00105e10 _TFC4Halo28FullPatientViewTableViewCell19collapseButtonPressfS0_FCSo8UIButtonT_ + 6208
    25  Halo                                0x0010645d _TToFC4Halo28FullPatientViewTableViewCell19collapseButtonPressfS0_FCSo8UIButtonT_ + 61
    26  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0324a0b5 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    27  UIKit                               0x01d8016a -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 118
    28  UIKit                               0x01d800e9 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    29  UIKit                               0x01f1e19f -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 79
    30  UIKit                               0x01f1e51f -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 408
    31  UIKit                               0x01f1d525 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 714
    32  UIKit                               0x022efeaa _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 12763
    33  UIKit                               0x01dfabdf -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1559
    34  UIKit                               0x01dfc298 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1137
    35  UIKit                               0x01da1efb -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 266
    36  UIKit                               0x01d77cb6 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7802
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x00d49d1f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x00d3f9ab __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x00d3edc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x00d3e706 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x00d3e51b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    42  GraphicsServices                    0x058c0664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x058c04a1 GSEventRun + 104
    44  UIKit                               0x01d7e1eb UIApplicationMain + 160
    45  Halo                                0x0011eb6c main + 140
    46  libdyld.dylib                       0x03ceca21 start + 1
    47  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The stack is not very helpful to me and I can't even figure out the opening message: "insertObject:atIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]."  No where in this sample and my test with a single table entry should there be an index of '2.'  Any help you could provide would be appreciated.

Here's my 'bt' on this exception:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xc9ca7, 0x0401969a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0401969a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x03fe4634 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 101
    frame #2: 0x03d9339d libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 156
    frame #3: 0x04034ae7 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 151
    frame #4: 0x04055683 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 300
    frame #5: 0x032360b6 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 108
    frame #6: 0x04052d0d libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 14
    frame #7: 0x0405293e libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 103
    frame #8: 0x03235fad libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 47
    frame #9: 0x00d3e7d0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 672
    frame #10: 0x00d3e51b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #11: 0x058c0664 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
    frame #12: 0x058c04a1 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #13: 0x01d7e1eb UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 160
  * frame #14: 0x0011eb6c Halo`main + 140 at AppDelegate.swift:26
    frame #15: 0x03ceca21 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Per request, here's the code followed by the output:

```
    // Retrieve Current Table View and Animate Changes
    let tableView = self.superview!.superview as! UITableView

    // Test Output
    print( "tableView.numberOfSections: \(tableView.numberOfSections)" )
    print( "tableView.numberOfRowsInSection( sender.tag ): \(tableView.numberOfRowsInSection( sender.tag ))" )

    // Reload Section with Animation
    tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet( index: sender.tag ), withRowAnimation: animation )

    tableView.numberOfSections: 1
    tableView.numberOfRowsInSection( sender.tag ): 1
```

Comment: It is hard to figure out where the problem is by just seeing the crash log.

Comment: It seems that you have an empty array but `numberOfRowsInSection` is still returning 2.  Please show `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: What else can I provide? I'd be happy to. The debugger doesn't let me dive into the .reloadSections() call at all.  It just crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section of the stack trace (probably) means that you have an `IBOutletCollection`, and UIKit is now trying to populate it from a storyboard or nib:

```
7   UIKit                               0x024f4d4f -[UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection performConnect] + 964
8   UIKit                               0x024f4daf -[UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection connect] + 33
```

And this section looks like it’s trying to add bound objects to an existing array:

```
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00cdd211 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 881
3   Foundation                          0x01510134 -[NSKeyValueSlowMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:] + 115
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d38630 -[NSMutableArray insertObjects:count:atIndex:] + 192
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00d38322 -[NSMutableArray insertObjectsFromArray:range:atIndex:] + 322
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00d381c2 -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:] + 834
```

All of that means that the error may not have anything to do with the code you posted, but rather with your nib and how it interacts with the properties it’s bound to.

Take a look at whether you’re using an `IBOutletCollection`, and if so, start debugging the things it’s bound to.

Comment: I was just coming back to post my solution.  You're right in that it's related to an IBOutletCollection.  To clear my mind, I went ahead and cleaned up these issues: "WARNING: A Gesture recognizer ... was setup in a storyboard/xib to be added to more than one view ... at a time, this was never allowed, and is now enforced. Beginning with iOS 9.0 it will be put in the first view it is loaded into." and this cleared everything up. The stack trace was no help to me and I tinkered and found that I could step through "cellForRowAtIndexPath." Stems from multiple cell Identifiers in a TableView.